# asio socket, inside a class declaration, scope issue

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I want to have a class inside which I initialize and open a tcp socket, but I want to repeatedly write to the socket only by calling a method of that class, without having to re-establish connection everytime.

My code is below. I get the compile time errors as pasted here below the code block.
The method is unable to see the socket that was initialized in the constructor. Seems to be a simple C++ "scope" issue, but beats me!

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using asio::ip::udp;
using asio::ip::tcp;

class rpcClass {
    char sendBuffer[16];
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint epdPt;
    asio::io_service io_service;
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endPt;

public:
    rpcClass () {                // constructor
    asio::ip::tcp::socket socketTCP(io_service);
    strcpy (sendBuffer, "*Constructor*\n");
    endPt = asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"),\
         boost::lexical_cast<int>(5004));
    socketTCP.connect(endPt);
    socketTCP.write_some (asio::buffer(sendBuffer));
    };

    void sendRPCData (void) {    //send data when called from main()
        strcpy (sendBuffer, "rpcData\n");
        socketTCP.write_some (asio::buffer(sendBuffer));
    };
};


int main(void)  {

    rpcClass    rpc; // I WANT THE rpc OBJECT TO SEND DATA
    rpc.sendRPCData ();  // ONLY WHEN THIS METHOD IS CALLED
    return (0);
}
```

Here is the error output (Eclipse)

```
rpc-class.cpp: In member function ‘void rpcClass::sendRPCData()’:
rpc-class.cpp: error: ‘socketTCP’ was not declared in this scope
```

Thanks a lot for helping!
-pn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `socketTCP` as a local variable in the constructor, not a member variable of the class.

That means you can't use it in other functions.

Presumably you meant to declare a member variable, and initialize that in the constructor instead of a local variable.